# Assigning certain Years to a number in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R so any help would be very appreciated.

I have a df 'players' that features a column of dates between years 2003-2018. Here is a sample of how the df looks:

```
Start             Apps
01/01/2003         10
06/05/2006         42
23/01/2004         23
30/06/2010         34
11/06/2006         23
21/01/2005         45
12/07/2004          3
03/01/2010         76
01/01/2009         34
```

Is there any way I can set data from each any day of each year to equal a number, e.g any date from '2003' = 1, any date from '2004' = 2, any date from'2005' = 3 etc. so that the output could look something like this:

```
Year             Apps       YearValue
01/01/2003         10           1
06/05/2006         42           4
23/01/2004         23           2
30/06/2010         34           8
11/06/2006         23           4
21/01/2005         45           3
12/07/2004          3           2
03/01/2010         76           8
01/01/2009         34           7
```

Comment: Your first concern (as akrun is resolving) is to make sure the `Year` column is something other than a string, i.e., a class of either `Date` or `POSIXt` (date/time). While it is certainly feasible to work with dates as strings, the overhead of trying to match years or anything else in an ordinal/discrete fashion is onerous at best. Converting it to a date each time might be inefficient if you have to do repeated similar calculations, you might consider converting it "permanently" with `players$Year <- lubridate::dmy(players$Year)` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

We extract the `year` from the 'Start' column, coerces the `factor` converted 'year' to `integer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(YearValue = as.integer(factor(year(dmy(Start)), levels = 2003:2010))) %>% 
   rename(Year = Start)
#        Year Apps YearValue
#1 01/01/2003   10         1
#2 06/05/2006   42         4
#3 23/01/2004   23         2
#4 30/06/2010   34         8
#5 11/06/2006   23         4
#6 21/01/2005   45         3
#7 12/07/2004    3         2
#8 03/01/2010   76         8
#9 01/01/2009   34         7
```

---

As @Parfait mentioned in the comments, a `base R` equivalent would be

```
within(df, { 
           Start <- as.Date(Start, format="%d/%m/%Y")
           Year <- as.integer(format(Start, format="%Y"))
          YearValue <- as.integer(factor(Year, levels = 2003:2010))
          rm(Year)
         })
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Start = c("01/01/2003", "06/05/2006", "23/01/2004", 
"30/06/2010", "11/06/2006", "21/01/2005", "12/07/2004", "03/01/2010", 
"01/01/2009"), Apps = c(10L, 42L, 23L, 34L, 23L, 45L, 3L, 76L, 
34L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: And for tinyverse (i.e., base R) counterpart: `within(df, { Start <- as.Date(Start, format="%d/%m/%Y"); Year <- as.integer(format(Start, format="%Y")); YearValue <- as.integer(factor(Year, levels = 2003:2010)); rm(Year)})`

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of those cases where we overthink the problem. Once you extract the year for each date, all you're trying to do is count chronologically from there. That means just subtracting 2002 from every year, so that 2003 (the first year) is 1. More flexibly, subtract the earliest year, then add 1.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(Year = lubridate::dmy(Start) %>% lubridate::year()) %>%
  mutate(YearStart = Year - min(Year) + 1)
#>        Start Apps Year YearStart
#> 1 01/01/2003   10 2003         1
#> 2 06/05/2006   42 2006         4
#> 3 23/01/2004   23 2004         2
#> 4 30/06/2010   34 2010         8
#> 5 11/06/2006   23 2006         4
#> 6 21/01/2005   45 2005         3
#> 7 12/07/2004    3 2004         2
#> 8 03/01/2010   76 2010         8
#> 9 01/01/2009   34 2009         7
```

Drop the `Year` column if you need—I left it here just to show.